# Can't render data from mongodb to handlebar template

Tags: mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I am unable to load data(from MongoDB) to the handlebar template engine.when I console.log ArticleModel.find() its show data.But can't render data in the template engine.

Thanks in advance.

**App.js**

```
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars"); //Loads the handlebars module
let ArticleModel = require("./model/article");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoDB = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/article";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

//Sets handlebars configurations (we will go through them later on)
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  handlebars({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts",
    extname: "hbs",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials/"
  })
);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  ArticleModel.find({}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("main", { layout: "index", data: result });
    }
  });
});

//stating server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**main.hbs**

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>

<ul>

{{#each data}}
<li>{{title}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```